# Material Data Table not showing updated data

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material, onchange

My material data table doesn't show/update when the input data is changed. Only if I call the refresh function from a button. Inside the ngOnChanges, the refresh doesn't work either. 
How do I update the view of the table except by calling the refresh function via a button?

```
export interface VariableObject {
  name: string;
  node: string;
  status: string;
  subscriber: any;
  type: string;
  value: any;
}
```

Component

```
@Input() data: VariableObject[];
displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'type', 'status', 'value'];
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<VariableObject>();

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<VariableObject>(this.data); }

refresh() {
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<VariableObject>(this.data); }
```

Comment: What about using `ChangeDetectionRef.detectChanges()` in the `onChanges` after the assignment?

Comment: Do you have a ChangeDetectionStrategy of `OnPush` in this Component?

Comment: Doesn't work. I've added changeDetection with OnPush, but the data table is still emtpy, even after receiving the updated data.

Comment: I was just asking if you had that? It won't work if you had that. But should work if you don't. There's something else that's wrong. It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can use [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to create one.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uuqesq

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, Angular doesn't recognize if an object has changed. It can only listen to changes on variables and (probably) properties of objects.

Maybe you could listen on a different variable, triggering the event when it gets modified on data change

The following is a workaround:

`this.ObjectName = Object.assign({}, this.ObjectName);`

That way Angular detects the change and fires `ngOnChanges`. You will have to reassign your object in the parent component.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21493902)

Comment: I edited my answer to make my point clear wich was that the angular check system sometimes is flawed when it comes to objects and arrays. Which answers why ngOnchanges doesnt fire @CozyAzure